# Where can I download Dundee Corpus?

Tags: corpus

Dundee Corpus (Kennedy et al., 2003) is an open eye-tracking corpus with tokenization and measures similar to the Dundee Treebank (Barrett et al., 2015). The corpus contains eye-tracking recordings of ten native English-speaking subjects reading 20 newspaper articles from The Independent.

**But I cannot find this data from the Internet. Can anybody tell me where I can download this dataset or offer it to me?**

---

[Kennedy et al., 2003] Alan Kennedy, Robin Hill, and Jo¨el
Pynte. The dundee corpus. Proceedings of the 12th European
conference on eye movement, 2003.

[Barrettetal.2015] Maria Barrett, Zˇeljko Agic ́, and Anders Søgaard. 2015. The dundee treebank. In The 14th International Workshop on Treebanks and Lin- guistic Theories (TLT 14).

Answer (score 1):

Because of licensing restrictions, I don't think it's freely available. As a close approximation, you can download syntactic trees built off of it, like: http://www.ling.ohio-state.edu/golddundee/#kennedy